# netCDF4 multi-file dataset

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm using netCDF4 in Python to handle `.netcdf` files. For example, say I have two files representing measurements from the same locations in different years, which both have dimensions:
longitude(5), latitude(5), time(365). I should be able to combine them into one `netCDF4` dataset with dimensions longitude(5), latitude(5), time(730), since the spatial coordinates are identical. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are different options available in Python. One is my package [nctoolkit](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/).

You could merge two files and save them as a new file as follows:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
# open a multi-file dataset
ds = nc.open_data(["foo1.nc", "foo2.nc"])
# merge along the time coordinates
ds.merge("time")
# save the merged dataset to a file
ds.to_nc("foo_bar.nc")
```